# How to use Python to acquire auto run program

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, command-line, subprocess

#### 1. Background

- I'm using an atmospheric simulation model (named **WRF**) now. The model is controlled by its own control file **namelist.input**
- When I want to simulate the atmospheric situation for certain period, I just need to change the start time and end time in the **namelist.input**, and then run the model

  `vim namelist.input ## Change the simulated period
  mpirun np -16 ./wrf.exe`

#### 2. My attempt

When the target period is large enough (e.g 1 year), the long computation time will decrease the stability of the results. (Someone may be familiar with *The Butterfly Effect*: even littile difference of the simulated results compared with reality will become huge if the computation kept so long)

So, I need to divide the simulated period into several sub-part and run the model multiple times.  There is a `.csh` file written by one researcher  can achieve my target. I uploaded it here as an reference.

```
#!/bin/csh -f

set year = "2013"


foreach strtime (010106010600 010512011100) ## just show two periods here
set smon = `echo ${strtime}|cut -c1-2`
set sday = `echo ${strtime}|cut -c3-4`
set shr  = `echo ${strtime}|cut -c5-6`
set emon = `echo ${strtime}|cut -c7-8`
set eday = `echo ${strtime}|cut -c9-10`
set ehr  = `echo ${strtime}|cut -c11-12`

cat > namelist.input << EOF
 start_year                          = ${year},${year},
 start_month                         = ${smon},${smon},
 start_day                           = ${sday},${sday},
 start_hour                          = ${shr},${shr},
 end_year                            = ${year},${year},
 end_month                           = ${emon},${emon},
 end_day                             = ${eday},${eday},
 end_hour                            = ${ehr},${ehr},
 ... # the .csh file contain all content of __namelist.input__ with start and end time changes.  

EOF

# running  wrf
 mpirun -np 16 ./wrf.exe
end
```

I want to **write a Python program as the replacement of the csh file**. Python language is more powerful (I can post-process the output files in the same **.py** program)

#### 3. My issues

I have tried to write a .py program for autorun the WRF model several time. It contains three major elements:

- Setting the start time and corresponding end time as a **list**, and then **loop** the list for re-run.
- Changing the **namelist.input** with the varying time period.
- Run command line program within python environment.

  ```
   from subprocess import call
   call(["mpirun", "-np 16 ./wrf.exe"])
  ```

But I'm confused with the re-start time spot.

> By the words, **how to test one single run is over and I need to re-run the model for the next period within Python**.

Comment: The `subprocess.call` will not return unless the given command (in this case mpirun) finishes. So you could repeatedly invoke the `call` function using for/while loop. Could explain your requirement?

Comment: Maybe I used `subprocess.call` wrongly. In terminal, I typed `mpirun xxx` to execute the program. I want to do the same thing inside Python script

Comment: I tried `os.system("mpirun xxx")`. it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

So the question is: How to check if the process is still running?

Possible solutions:

1) create start manager script that executes the model and checks if the other process is complete in a while loop? Or make a function call at the end of your model?

2) Do something at the end of each period, write simple text file or something like that. And that gets picked up by another process.

3) Check if the exe is running by using psutil
https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil

```
    import psutil

    def is_alive():

        for pid in psutil.pids():
            p = psutil.Process(pid)
            if p.name() == "wrf.exe":
                print("Process is alive")
                return True

        return False
```